# Graphing n restrictions Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to graph a loop with the range of an user answer. The problem is that my graph isn't showing the functions. 
I have this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
res=int(input('¿Cuántas restricciones son? (ax1+bx2+c=0) '))
i=0

numresa = []
numresb = []
numresc = []
for i in range(res):
    resa= float(input(f'Coeficiente (a) de restricción {i} '))
    numresa.append(resa)
    resb = float(input(f'Coeficiente (b) de restricción {i} '))
    numresb.append(resb)
    resc= float(input(f'Coeficiente (c) de restricción {i} '))
    numresc.append(resc)

for i in range(res):
    x1 = np.linspace(0, 800, res)
    x2 = -x1 * numresa[i] / numresb[i]
    plt.plot(x1, x2, color="red")
plt.show()
```

Comment: The line `x1 = np.linspace(0, 800, res)` is strange. What do you want this to do, eg, when `res=1`? Have you tried this with `res = 4`? Also, at least for SO, unless you have a problem about user input, it's more helpful to ask using fixed values, so we can all be referencing the same situation.  Please edit the question to use specific values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem with this

```
x1=np.linspace(-100, 100, 256, endpoint=True)

for i in range(res):
    x2 = -x1 * numresa[i] - numresc[i]/ numresb[i]
    plt.plot(x1, x2, color="red")
```

Comment: You need `x2 = (-x1 * numresa[i] - numresc[i]) / numresb[i]` for the equation `ax1+bx2+c=0`